# Displaying users current location on google maps and updating it

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Currently I have a small program that loads google maps centred on my desired location. The user will be in this location, however I want to have a marker on the users location that is constantly updating, so they can see where they are in relation to the map as they move. I am aiming to get the same logo as in the google maps app, the blue circle with an arrow. Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Javascript - The code is taken from the google developer page for a map overlay, I have the overlay section removed right now but the map is working fine.

```
<script>
// This example creates a custom overlay called USGSOverlay, containing
// a U.S. Geological Survey (USGS) image of the relevant area on the map.

// Set the custom overlay object's prototype to a new instance
// of OverlayView. In effect, this will subclass the overlay class therefore
// it's simpler to load the API synchronously, using
// google.maps.event.addDomListener().
// Note that we set the prototype to an instance, rather than the
// parent class itself, because we do not wish to modify the parent class.

var overlay;
USGSOverlay.prototype = new google.maps.OverlayView();

// Initialize the map and the custom overlay.

function initMap() {
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
        zoom: 16,
        center: {
            lat: 43.4678683,
            lng: -79.7006069
        },
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.SATELLITE
    });

    var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(
        new google.maps.LatLng(43.46344509, -79.70671354),
        new google.maps.LatLng(43.47341076, -79.69298207));


}

/** @constructor */
function USGSOverlay(bounds, image, map) {

    // Initialize all properties.
    this.bounds_ = bounds;
    this.image_ = image;
    this.map_ = map;

    // Define a property to hold the image's div. We'll

    // actually create this div upon receipt of the onAdd()
    // method so we'll leave it null for now.
    this.div_ = null;

    // Explicitly call setMap on this overlay.
    this.setMap(map);
}


/**
 * onAdd is called when the map's panes are ready and the overlay has been
 * added to the map.
 */
USGSOverlay.prototype.onAdd = function () {

    var div = document.createElement('div');
    div.style.borderStyle = 'none';
    div.style.borderWidth = '0px';
    div.style.position = 'absolute';

    // Create the img element and attach it to the div.
    var img = document.createElement('img');
    img.src = this.image_;
    img.style.width = '100%';
    img.style.height = '100%';
    img.style.position = 'absolute';
    div.appendChild(img);

    this.div_ = div;

    // Add the element to the "overlayLayer" pane.
    var panes = this.getPanes();
    panes.overlayLayer.appendChild(div);
};

USGSOverlay.prototype.draw = function () {

    // We use the south-west and north-east
    // coordinates of the overlay to peg it to the correct position and size.
    // To do this, we need to retrieve the projection from the overlay.
    var overlayProjection = this.getProjection();

    // Retrieve the south-west and north-east coordinates of this overlay
    // in LatLngs and convert them to pixel coordinates.
    // We'll use these coordinates to resize the div.
    var sw = overlayProjection.fromLatLngToDivPixel(this.bounds_.getSouthWest());
    var ne = overlayProjection.fromLatLngToDivPixel(this.bounds_.getNorthEast());

    // Resize the image's div to fit the indicated dimensions.
    var div = this.div_;
    div.style.left = sw.x + 'px';
    div.style.top = ne.y + 'px';
    div.style.width = (ne.x - sw.x) + 'px';
    div.style.height = (sw.y - ne.y) + 'px';
};

// The onRemove() method will be called automatically from the API if
// we ever set the overlay's map property to 'null'.
USGSOverlay.prototype.onRemove = function () {
    this.div_.parentNode.removeChild(this.div_);
    this.div_ = null;
};

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initMap);
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: I'm not sure how to place a current location icon. So an arrow or other tracker that would be on the users location and constantly update as they move.

Comment: Have you seen the [GeoLocatonMarker library](http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/geolocationmarker/docs/reference.html)? (fix link in comment)

Answer (score 0):

You should have some function to update the user location.  Then once you have the location (lat and long)

just do this add a marker to the map:

```
 // use the lat and long values for the location you have
 var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(36.166461, -86.771289);


var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
position: (myLatlng),
data:this,
map: map, // this will add it to the map
title: 'user location'});
```

Id suggest you keep track of the marker then everytime th euser location changed you simply update the position of the marker rather than creating a new marker like this:

```
  var myNewLocation = new google.maps.LatLng(-36.8485,174.7633);
  marker.setPosition(myNewLocation);
```

To set an icon on your marker  you do this:

```
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
position: (myLatlng),
data:this,
map: map, // this will add it to the map
icon: new google.maps.MarkerImage("url to where your icon is",
                        new google.maps.Size(32, 32),
                        new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
                        new google.maps.Point(16, 32))
title: 'user location'});
```

Here is a JS Fiddle to help you: https://jsfiddle.net/loanburger/48asvsed/